# Centos7: Website Not Loading

Tags: linux, unix, apache-http-server, webserver, computer-architecture

Having trouble getting a website orcanutrition.com to load on a new server.  Pings to the proper IP.

Here is my scenario

```
[root@s233403 www]# sudo httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   orcanutrition.com (/etc/httpd
/conf.d/orcanutrition.com.conf:1)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server orcanutrition.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/orcanutrition.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost orcanutrition.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/orcanutrition.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.orcanutrition.com
         port 443 namevhost s233403.cloud.flynet.pro (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: _RH_HAS_HTTPPROTOCOLOPTIONS
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName orcanutrition.com
ServerAlias www.orcanutrition.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/orcanutrition.com/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/orcanutrition.com-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/orcanutrition.com-access.log combined

<Directory "/var/www/orcanutrition.com/public_html">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.orcanutrition.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =orcanutrition.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>


[root@s233403 www]# ping orcanutrition.com
PING orcanutrition.com (193.47.34.151) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from finishes.orcanutrition.com (193.47.34.151): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
64 bytes from finishes.orcanutrition.com (193.47.34.151): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from finishes.orcanutrition.com (193.47.34.151): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
^C
```

port 80, 443 are open

Comment: "got an error when restarting apache" what error? Please update the question.

Comment: updated post.  Thank you for the reply.